# Tensorflow: Manipulate bias during training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I train a model and want to manipulate all bias terms during training. For this reason, I build the graph using a parameter `change_bias`

```
change_bias = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = change_bias * b
```

To manipulate the bias term, I want to be able to feed `change_bias=0.1` if I want the bias to decrease.

My approach does not work. What is the right way to manipulate the biases of a model during training?

Answer (score 0):

because of b is defined as variable this is wrong:

```
b = change_bias * b
```

try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[-1,26])
change_bias=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[])
b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([26]),name="bias")

output=x+tf.math.multiply(b,change_bias)
```

edit: change_bias must be scalar